# Error on tabular latex

Tags: tables

I'm getting an error on latex and don't understand why ...
The purpose was to create some tables on latex, but it is getting me some error which i don't really understand ...
Any hint for me please ?
Thank you :)

error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.5 \begin{tabular}{ | 1 | p{5cm} |}
```

code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ | 1 | p{5cm} |}
\hline
Nome & Manuel da Silva
 \\ \line 
Data de nascimento & 1977 \\ \line 
Data de falecimento & 2011 \\ \line 
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{ | 1 | p{5cm} |}
\hline
Nome & Ana da Silva
 \\ \line 
Data de nascimento & 2006 \\ \line 
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{ | 1 | p{5cm} |}
\hline
Nome & Maria Felisbina
 \\ \line 
Data de nascimento & 1980 \\ \line 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error comes from using `1` (the number one) instead of an `l` (the letter l, for left) in the column specification. The valid column specifiers, without loading any packages, are `l` (left aligned content), `c` (centered content), `r` (right aligned content) and `p{<width>}` (content set in a `\parbox` of width `<width>`).

You also have to change  `\line` to `\hline`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ | l | p{5cm} |}
\hline
Nome & Manuel da Silva
 \\ \hline 
Data de nascimento & 1977 \\ \hline 
Data de falecimento & 2011 \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{ | l | p{5cm} |}
\hline
Nome & Ana da Silva
 \\ \hline 
Data de nascimento & 2006 \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{ | l | p{5cm} |}
\hline
Nome & Maria Felisbina
 \\ \hline 
Data de nascimento & 1980 \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```