# xltabular error - Misplaced \noalign. \end{xltabular}

Tags: longtable, tabularx, xltabular

My latex code throws the following error when compiled: `Misplaced \noalign. \end{xltabular}`
I could not figure out the reason for it. It always showed that the error occurred on the final line `\end{xltabular}`. It also shows that other commands are outside of the tabular environment.
Here is an abstract MWE of my code:

```
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|||X||X|||}
\caption{randomCaption}
\label{randomLabel}

\hline
col1 & col2 \\
\hline\hline
\endhead

\blindtext  & \blindtext \newline
\blindtext \newline
\blindtext \newline
\blindtext \newline
\blindtext \newline

\blindtext  & \blindtext \newline
\blindtext \newline
\blindtext \newline
\blindtext \newline
\blindtext \newline
\blindtext \newline
\blindtext \\
\hline

\blindtext  & \blindtext \newline
\blindtext \newline
\blindtext \newline
\blindtext \newline
\blindtext \newline
\blindtext \newline
\blindtext \\
\hline
\end{xltabular}
```

It is my intention that the following code creates two colums where the second half after the & is a multi row text:

```
\blindtext \newline
\blindtext \newline
\blindtext \newline
\blindtext \newline
\blindtext \newline
\blindtext \\
\hline
```

In general, the table is really long and spreads over several pages. I would also need the heading to repeat which is why I I used "\endhead".

I already searched for solutions in the following sources (and other): (However, I was not successful)

1. https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Errors/Extra%20alignment%20tab%20has%20been%20changed%20to%20%5Ccr
2. https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Errors/Misplaced_%5Cnoalign
3. [Error on tabular latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117127/error-on-tabular-latex)

I appreciate any kind of help.Thank you!

Comment: Hi and welcome! Maybe you can explain in a few words why the content of those links doesn't work for you ?

Comment: You seem to think a blank line in a table is like a `\\` (`\tabularnewline`). This is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the error, add a `\\` right after the `\label` command as in

```
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|||X||X|||}
\caption{randomCaption}
\label{randomLabel}\\

\hline
col1 & col2 \\
```

There is also a second `\\` missing: right before the second occurence of `\blindtext  & \blindtext`. (This results in an " Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr." error).

Comment: That fixed it. I m very thankful. Thanks!